# add own text inside nested braces

Tags: python, pyparsing, text-processing

I have this source of text which contains HTML tags and PHP code at the same time:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo "title here"; ?></title>
<head>
 <body>
  <h1 <?php echo "class='big'" ?>>foo</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

and I need place my own text (for example: MY_TEXT) after opened  tag and get this result:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo "title here"; ?></title>
<head>
 <body>
  <h1 <?php echo "class='big'" ?>>MY_TEXTfoo</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

thus I need consider nested braces

if I will use regex it will creates problems (I need consider any level of nested braces). I need another strategy.

now my idea try to use pyparsing, but I can't get it now, too complicated for my current level

could anybody make solution please?

Comment: Why do you think python will help you in this case?
You can handle this very specific case both with regexp, or python (somehow) [If only you can predict level of nested quotes].
Neither are silver bulllet.
What do you want to achieve in the end ?

Comment: If you do expect python will help you to extract aribitary-nested php code easily - you're gravely wrong, it won't (without much effort)

Comment: 1. My project requires python based solution. With regex I will get a lot of pain, as I know regex doesn't good idea for similar tasks (nested structures), I have read about it here on SO in similar threads

2. I don't need extract PHP code, I need only detect end of <h1> tag (to place there my text after first opened tag), that's all

Comment: RegExp cannot handle arbitrary open/close tags in general case, you're absolutely correct about it...
Just not sure why do you want to mix PHP with Python. The solution will be almost the same for these.
Smart count of open and close tags is a way to go. Standard Python library does not provide any out-of-box solution for it, neither PHP does, as I know

Comment: Thanks for thoughts dear, yes I was thinking about this idea to count opened/closed braces, but it seemed to me that its wrong idea, I tried to make some samples with pyparsing and noticed that this tool is right choice, I had some results with it but I can't used it now, too low skills. If nobody will helps me I will try this your idea, but I hope guys will show examples with pyparsing, I am sure totally that this task can be easily solved with pyparsing.

something similar I found here http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/tagCapture.py/159054171/tagCapture.py

Comment: but I can't change this sample to solve my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyparsing has a helper method called `nestedExpr` that makes it easy to match strings of nested open/close delimiters. Since you have nested PHP tags within your `<h1>` tag, then I would use a `nestedExpr` like:

```
nested_angle_braces = nestedExpr('<', '>')
```

However, this will match *every* tag in your input HTML source:

```
for match in nested_angle_braces.searchString(html):
    print match
```

gives:

```
[['html']]
[['head']]
[['title']]
[['?php', 'echo', '"title here"', ';', '?']]
[['/title']]
[['head']]
[['body']]
[['h1', ['?php', 'echo', '"class=\'big\'"', '?']]]
[['/h1']]
[['/body']]
[['/html']]
```

You want to match *only* those tags whose opening text is 'h1'. We can add a condition to an expression in pyparsing using `addCondition`:

```
nested_angle_braces_with_h1 = nested_angle_braces().addCondition(
                                            lambda tokens: tokens[0][0].lower() == 'h1')
```

Now we will match only the desired tag. Just a few more steps...

First of all, `nestedExpr` gives back nested lists of matched items. We want the original text that was matched. Pyparsing includes another helper for that, unimaginatively named `originalTextFor` - we combine this with the previous definition to get:

```
nested_angle_braces_with_h1 = originalTextFor(
    nested_angle_braces().addCondition(lambda tokens: tokens[0][0].lower() == 'h1')
    )
```

Lastly, we have to add one more parse-time callback action, to append "MY_TEXT" to the tag:

```
nested_angle_braces_with_h1.addParseAction(lambda tokens: tokens[0] + 'MY_TEXT')
```

Now that we are able to match the desired `<h1>` tag, we can use `transformString` method of the expression to do the search-and-replace work for us:

```
print(nested_angle_braces_with_h1.transformString(html))
```

With your original sample saved as a variable named `html`, we get:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo "title here"; ?></title>
<head>
        <body>
                <h1 <?php echo "class='big'" ?>>MY_TEXTfoo</h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

Note: this will add "MY_TEXT" after *every* `<h1>` tag. If you want this to be applied *only* after `<h1>` tags containing PHP, then write the appropriate condition and add it to `nested_angle_braces_with_h1`.

Comment: thanks a lot dear! brilliant! works perfect! you are god! and you explaination is the best! but sorry guy I have no enough reputation thus I am not able to vote for your post :(

Comment: hello dear, thanks a lot for your efforts, I really appreciate it, all works perfect but today I got new serious problem with your code, please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851504/add-own-text-inside-nested-braces-exception